# How I can verify Text is present or not in robot framework?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to use the following syntax but can anyone tell me how I can use this as an example?

```
Element Should Contain locator, expected, message=
```

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601126/how-to-check-if-a-text-is-in-web-page-in-robot-framework-and-selenium  It's something similar to your issue I guess.

Comment: Best answer with more options - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242291/robotframework-how-to-check-text-on-page

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are expecting a particular locator to get value as "Payment was successful", so firstly store that in temp variable "response" and finds its value by "Get Text" and then compare it.

```
 ${response}    Get Text    xpath=/html/body/div/tr[2]/td/strong
 Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response}    Payment was successful
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this keyword

[Element Text Should Be](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Element%20Text%20Should%20Be)